# Problems binding an F# event in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, f#

In a custom WPF control class MyControl (F#) I define an event

```
let viewportUpdatedEvent = Event<EventHandler<_>, _>()

[<CLIEvent>]
member __.ViewportUpdated = viewportUpdatedEvent.Publish
```

I try to bind this event in XAML to an handler in a C# WPF application

```
<MyControl ViewportUpdated="OnViewportUpdated"></MyControl>
```

Note that this is done using the Properties Pane in Visual Studio, so the event is recognized. The auto-generated method has the following signature:

```
private void OnViewportUpdated(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
```

However, the project doesn't compile and gives this error:

> Error CS1061  'MyControl' does not contain a definition for 'ViewportUpdated' and no accessible extension method 'ViewportUpdated' accepting a first argument of type 'MyControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

dotnet --version is 8.0.100-preview.4.23260.5